# How to read a series of items under a child node in Firebase using FirebaseAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

As the title states, I'm trying to read a bunch of nodes under a nested node in Firebase, and display the information using FirebaseAdapter. I'm using the parseSnapshot method to try and grab the information I need but I think I'm misunderstanding exactly *how* to go about getting the information.  The user section of the database is structured like so:

[image]

I want *only* the information under UserInfo, and so I currently have the following code setup to intialize a recyclerview adapter (which gets the information)

```
private fun setupRequiredRecyclerView() {
    val requiredItems = private_items_recycler
    val context = this
    val userDataRef = mDatabaseReference.child("Users/${prefs.UID}/UserInfo")
    val mAdapter = RequiredItemsAdapter(User::class.java, R.layout.privaterecyclerview_item_row, RequiredProfileItemsViewHolder::class.java, userDataRef, context)

    //load data into adapter
    requiredItems.adapter = mAdapter

    //add divider between items
    requiredItems.addItemDecoration(Utilities.createDivider(this))

}
```

But the data snapshot I get back in the parseSnapshot method only seems to contain "dateJoined" and no other nodes, I'm guessing there's something wrong with my reference, but I don't know how to structure it - going up to `"Users/UID"` gets me everything *but* it also gets me UserInfoComplete, which I don't want (and as far as I know, there's no way to ignore that data in parseSnapshot, as FirebaseAdapter grabs every child node)

Does anyone out there know how exactly I need to structure my database reference to only get the UserInfo data?

(If necessary, this is my current parseSnapshot method):

```
override fun parseSnapshot(snapshot: DataSnapshot?): User {
    lateinit var user : User

    Log.i("Snapshot Data", snapshot!!.value.toString())

    var dateJoined = snapshot!!.value
    var dateOfBirth = snapshot.child("dateOfBirth").value
    var gender = snapshot.child("Gender").value
    var location = snapshot.child("Location").value
    var phoneNumber = snapshot.child("phoneNumber").value

    Log.i("Snapshot Data", snapshot!!.value.toString())
    user.dateJoined = dateJoined as Long
    return user

}
```

Comment: What's the log output for Snapshot Data

Comment: `Snapshot Data: 1515167592063` which makes me wonder if each node under UserInfo is being treated as a separate snapshot and not all of it under one item

Comment: have you tried     `val  userInfo = snapshot!!.getValue(UserInfo::class.java)`? Whats the result? Can you also share your code where you attach the value listener?

Comment: I did! It throws an error and says something along the lines of "cannot cast Java.Lang.Long" to "User.class" - which makes sense, it's grabbing dateJoined, which is a Long, and tries to cast that to User - which won't work. I also do not actually attach a value event listener (from my understanding the FirebaseAdapter handles that itself) should I be doing that somewhere?

Comment: I haven't used the `FirebaseAdapter` myself, so that should be fine. But how come you tell the adapter to display `User::class.java` when you put in a reference on `UserInfo`? (`mDatabaseReference.child("Users/${prefs.UID}/UserInfo")`)

Comment: As a bit of clarification, what I'm trying to do here is create an Edit Profile page where a user can update their information and the app will update it and display it back in real time - the recyclerview would contain all the options (Gender, Location, DOB, etc.) and clicking on a row would allow them to edit that field. My main hiccup is trying to actually get the info from the database into the recyclerview fields, I *think* the current method I have will work, but I'm not sure what exactly I need to change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162657/discussion-between-florian-hansen-and-tai-m).